Problem with running solana program via anchorpy
I am trying to setup simple solana/anchor program (smart contract) and invoke it via python anchorpy  library.
solana version is 1.18.8 (tried it with 1.18.13 as well)
anchor version is 0.30
anchorpy version is 0.20.1
All are the latest versions
I am running against local testnet (solana-test-validator)
I build and deploy the simple program which just msg!("hello world");
When I try to load the IDL in anchorpy (Just the code from the example), I got following error:
solders.SerdeJSONError: data did not match any variant of untagged enum IdlAccountItem at line 26 column 8
It's unable to parse account field. Also, the metadata field seems to be a new version, because it expects name and other fields to be top level. It seems like a version problem but I have no idea what to do with it...
When I try to load the IDL of some program from the mainnet chain, it works OK.
Thx in advance
J.

Ok,  if someone stumbles upon the same problem - the anchorpy version has to be the same as anchor version. So currently, the anchorpy version is 0.20.1, so you need to downgrade your anchor to this version. avm install 0.20.1
